# Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method" when i run this simple code

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, runtime-error

I want to go to each worksheet in a workbook called "ETAT.xlsx" that is already opened and set the value of range("a14") to 150, but when I run this code I get a

> runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

What could be the problem please?

```
Sub testo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
         Workbooks("ETAT.xlsx").ws.Range("a14").Value = 150
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the workbook in your loop, otherwise by default it will refer to the workbook which is active when the code is executed. Think this should work.

```
Sub testo()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Workbooks("ETAT.xlsx").Worksheets
    ws.Range("a14").Value = 150
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't refer to a specific workbook it will refer to the active workbook (`ActiveWorkbook`), which may not be the workbook containing the macro (`ThisWorkbook`).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - quite right, thanks for spotting that, corrected above.